# How to use CASE statement in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

Framework: ASP.NET webforms.

I have two textboxes, one to input start datetime, and the other for end datetime. I also have a dropdownlist to allow users to select between "Local Time" and "UTC".

Scenarios are

1. If user selects "Local Time" in dropdownlist, retrieve result between `@StartDateTime` and `@EndDateTime` in `[LocalTimeColumn]` column
2. If user selects "UTC" in dropdownlist, retrieve result between `@StartDateTime` and `@EndDateTime` in `[UTCColumn]` column

The SQL query I wrote doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM [vmc]
WHERE 
    @DropDownList = CASE
                       WHEN @DropDownList = "Local Time"
                          THEN ([LocalTimeColumn] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime)
                          ELSE ([UTCColumn] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime)
                    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what follows `THEN` and `ELSE`) has to be a scalar value, rather than another logical expression.  You can make your `WHERE` clause do what you want with a slight refactor:

```
SELECT *
FROM [vmc]
WHERE
    (@DropDownList = "Local Time" AND
     [LocalTimeColumn] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime) OR
    [UTCColumn] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, your query doesn't work as "Local Time" is treated as a column. It should be a dropdownlist control instead of a column. Another thing is, I only have two textbox controls StartDateTime and StartDateTime, StartDate and EndDate are typo sorry about that